# Memory usage of tensorflow conv2d with large filters

Tags: memory, tensorflow, convolution

I have a tensorflow model with some relatively large `135 x 135 x 1 x 3` convolution filters. I find that `tf.nn.conv2d` becomes unusable for such large filters - it attempts to use well over 60GB of memory, at which point I need to kill it. Here is the minimum script to reproduce my error:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

frames, height, width, channels = 200, 321, 481, 1
filter_h, filter_w, filter_out = 5, 5, 3  # With this, output has shape (200, 317, 477, 3)
# filter_h, filter_w, filter_out = 7, 7, 3  # With this, output has shape (200, 315, 475, 3)
# filter_h, filter_w, filter_out = 135, 135, 3  # With this, output will be smaller than the above with shape (200, 187, 347, 3), but memory usage explodes

images = np.random.randn(frames, height, width, channels).astype(np.float32)

filters = tf.Variable(np.random.randn(filter_h, filter_w, channels, filter_out).astype(np.float32))
images_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
conv = tf.nn.conv2d(images_input, filters, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="VALID")

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    result = sess.run(conv, feed_dict={images_input: images})

print result.shape
```

First, can anyone explain this behavior? Why does memory usage blow up with filter size? (Note: I also tried changing my dimensions around to use a single `conv3d` instead of a batch of `conv2d`s, but this had the same problem)

Second, can anyone suggest a solution other than, say, breaking the operation up into 200 separate single-image convolutions?

**Edit:** After re-reading the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d) on `tf.nn.conv2d()`, I noticed this in the explanation of how it works:

> 1. Flattens the filter to a 2-D matrix with shape `[filter_height * filter_width * in_channels, output_channels]`.
> 2. Extracts image patches from the input tensor to form a virtual tensor of shape `[batch, out_height, out_width, filter_height * filter_width * in_channels]`.
> 3. For each patch, right-multiplies the filter matrix and the image patch vector.

I had originally taken this simply as a *description* of the process, but if tensorflow is actually extracting and storing separate filter-sized 'patches' from the image under the hood, then a back-of-the-envelope calculation shows that the intermediate computation involved requires ~130GB in my case, well over the limit that I could test.. This *might* answer my first question, but if so can anyone explain why TF would do this when I'm still only debugging on a CPU?

Comment: It actually does this specifically when you're debugging on the CPU - it does this because it turns convolution into matrix multiplication, so you can use linear algebra libraries to implement it. Running it on a GPU actually might need less memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I had originally taken this simply as a description of the process,
>   but if tensorflow is actually extracting and storing separate
>   filter-sized 'patches' from the image under the hood, then a
>   back-of-the-envelope calculation shows that the intermediate
>   computation involved requires ~130GB in my case, well over the limit
>   that I could test.

As you figured out yourself, this is the reason for the large memory consumption. Tensorflow does this because the filters are usually small and calculating a matrix multiplication is a lot faster than calculating a convolution.

> can anyone explain why TF would do this when I'm still only debugging
>   on a CPU?

You can also use tensorflow without having a GPU, therefore the CPU implementations are not just there for debugging. They are also optimized for speed and matrix multiplication is faster on both CPU and GPU.

To make convolutions with large filters possible you would have to implement a convolution for large filters in C++ and add it as a new op to tensorflow.