# why this simple model take large memory usage in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to implement a simple code for image segmentation. I only take two images of size 50 x 512 x 512 (depth, height, width) and two ground truth that have same size as corresponding images. But when i train a simple model with solely two images and ground truth. The RAM memory usage need to take about 6GB. And also when i set up size of minibatch from two to ten, it occur full RAM memory (it seems like memory leak). I do not understand why such a simple code can have memory problem.

Here's the code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import SimpleITK as sitk
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import zoom

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)

def tnet(inputs):
    conv1 = tf.layers.conv3d(inputs, 16, 5, padding='same')
    conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv1)
    logits = tf.layers.conv3d(conv1, 1, 1, padding='same')
    logits = tf.reshape(logits, [-1, 1])
    logits = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
    logits = tf.reshape(logits, [-1, 64, 128, 128, 1])
    return logits

def dice_coef(logits, labels):
    logits = tf.reshape(logits, [-1, 64 * 128 * 128 * 1])
    labels = tf.reshape(labels, [-1, 64 * 128 * 128 * 1])

    x = 2 * tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(logits, labels), axis=-1)
    y = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(logits, logits) + tf.multiply(labels, labels), axis=-1)
    z = tf.div(x, y)

    return tf.reduce_mean(z)

def dice_loss(logits, labels):
    return -dice_coef(logits, labels)

def loadTrainData():
    imageList = [
        '../data/train/Case00.mhd', '../data/train/Case01.mhd',
    ]
    GTList = [
        '../data/train/Case00_segmentation.mhd', '../data/train/Case01_segmentation.mhd',
    ]

    sitkImages = dict()

    rescalFilt = sitk.RescaleIntensityImageFilter()
    rescalFilt.SetOutputMaximum(1)
    rescalFilt.SetOutputMinimum(0)

    stats = sitk.StatisticsImageFilter()
    m = 0.

    for f in imageList:
        sitkImages[f] = rescalFilt.Execute(sitk.Cast(sitk.ReadImage(f), sitk.sitkFloat32))
        stats.Execute(sitkImages[f])
        m += stats.GetMean()

    sitkGT = dict()

    for f in GTList:
        sitkGT[f] = sitk.Cast(sitk.ReadImage(f), sitk.sitkFloat32)

    X_ = sorted(sitkImages.items())
    y_ = sorted(sitkGT.items())

    X_ = [sitk.GetArrayFromImage(d[1]) for d in X_]
    y_ = [sitk.GetArrayFromImage(l[1]) for l in y_]

    X = []
    y = []

    # SimpleITK.GetArrayFromImage() converts SimpleITK image to numpy
    for img in X_:
        X.append(zoom(img, (64 / img.shape[0], 128 / img.shape[1], 128 / img.shape[2])))
    for gt in y_:
        y.append(zoom(gt, (64 / gt.shape[0], 128 / gt.shape[1], 128 / gt.shape[2])))

    print("resized image shape : %s" % str(X[0].shape))
    print("resized gt shape : %s" % str(y[0].shape))

    return X, y

def preproc(images, labels):
    X = np.asarray(images, dtype=np.float32)
    y = np.asarray(labels, dtype=np.float32)

    print("all images shape : %s" % str(X.shape))
    print("all gts shape : %s" % str(y.shape))

    X = np.reshape(X, (-1, 64, 128, 128, 1))
    #    y = np.reshape(y, (-1, 64, 128, 128, 2))
    y = np.reshape(y, (-1, 64, 128, 128, 1))

    return X, y

def main(args):

    inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 64, 128, 128, 1])
    labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 64, 128, 128, 1])

    logits = tnet(inputs)

    cost = dice_loss(logits=logits, labels=labels)
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(cost)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        epochs = 10

        for epoch in range(epochs):
            print('yeah')

            # load and preprocess images
            X_, y_ = loadTrainData()
            X, y = preproc(X_, y_)

            _, cost_val = sess.run(
                [optimizer, cost],
                feed_dict={
                    inputs: X,
                    labels: y
                }
            )

            print('cost : ' + str(cost_val))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the convolution operation. if you have an image of 32x32 as inputs and you do `conv1 = tf.layers.conv3d(inputs, 16, 5, padding='same')` with 16 output channels,this will generate an output of shape of 32x32x16, the more convolution you make the more parameter and data will be added to your network`s graph, declare your session with the following configurations, it will show you how much memory is being consumed by each layer.

```
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True, 
                                        log_device_placement=True))
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. And i understand with a additional information [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45969666/memory-usage-of-tensorflow-conv2d-with-large-filters) to calculate memory spaces.